# Is there a way to exclude document files from the installation folder for vb.net project?

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, windows-installer

I have created a windows form application using vb.net 2019, and everything seems fine until I found out that an .xml document which contains confidential files like username and password appeared in the installation folder. With this file accessible for everybody, my project mean just nothing! Is there a way to fix this problem?
Regards!

Comment: What XML file? Why is it there in the first place? How are you creating this installer? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Probably you are talking about application settings file? The solution is simple - do not store secure information in the application settings, or use encryption (protected sections). Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203578/encrypting-sections-and-or-settings-in-an-app-config-file-that-will-be-redistrib

Comment: I used a .xml file (a text file) to store some tables like username and password,. And when I compile my project into a setup file and install in to a clients' computer, this .xml file appears in the installation folder. So, anyone can open this file via notepad and see what's stored inside.